# Are bech32 and base58 the only address formats?

Tags: bech32-address, address-format, base58check

Are bech32 and base58 the only formats that a Bitcoin address can use or is there another?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Base58 and bech32 are the only standardized address formats.

However, there exist standard ScriptPubKeys (the "locking" Script in the output) for which no address format is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. All legacy output types use *base58check* (which uses the *base58* encoding and adds a checksum) in their address encoding. Native segwit v0 outputs use [*bech32*](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki) addresses, while native segwit output v1 (P2TR) use the [*bech32m*](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0350.mediawiki) address encoding which is a slightly modified version of bech32. Future output types will likely also use *bech32m*.